# Implicitly convertible argument, but of ref type

Tags: c++, constructor, pass-by-reference, implicit-conversion, temporary-objects

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void foo(const std::string & s)
{
    std::cout << s;
}

const char * text = "something";


int main()
{
    foo( text );
}
```

I started wondering what is happening here because `gdb` reports `s == ""`. What is supposed to happen according to a recent (say `C++17`) version of the standard?

Via `https://godbolt.org/` I can see an `std::string` c-tor, so perhaps one is constructed and passed by reference, then destroyed upon function termination.

Comment: What do you mean by 'gdb reports `s == ""`'? The thing that's supposed to happen is that the program outputs "something". Whether you observe any particular thing if you peek behind the curtains in the debugger is not covered by the standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class template `std::basic_string` has implicit conversion constructor

```
basic_string(const charT* s, const Allocator& a = Allocator());
```

So in this call

```
foo( text );
```

a temporary object of the type `std::string` is created and a reference to it is used as an initializer of the function parameter. At the end of this statement the temporary object is destroyed.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows what is happening under the hood using a sample class.

```
#include <iostream>

class String
{
private:
    const char *s;

public:
    String( const char *s ) :s( s ) 
    {
        std::cout << "String( const char * ) is called\n";
    }

    ~String()
    {
        std::cout << "~String() is called\n";
    }

    friend std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &os, const String & s )
    {
        return os << s.s;
    }
};

void foo( const String & s )
{
    std::cout << s << '\n';
}

const char * text = "something";


int main()
{
    foo( text );
}
```

The program output is

```
String( const char * ) is called
something
~String() is called
```

The program will not work if the constructor would be declared with the function specifier `explicit`.

```
    explicit String( const char *s ) :s( s ) 
    {
        std::cout << "String( const char * ) is called\n";
    }
```

To make the program to work you will need to call the constructor explicitly. For example

```
foo( String( text ) );
```